# Bluemix - Can't select space in boilerplate

Tags: ibm-cloud

[Edited with new info]
I have created some spaces under my organization name in Bluemix successfully, using both Bluemix web interface & CLI.

I was trying to create an app from IoTFoundation Boilerplate by clicking the icon on the catalog. It leads me to the introduction page, and at the right hand side I was asked to select Space, Name, Host domain etc.

My problem is though I have spaces created and shown successfully in the Bluemix web interface, it is NOT POSSIBLE for me to select the space in the boilerplate. [new info: After > 10 minutes of creating the space using CLI, it finally appears in the boilerplate, however, the spaces created using Bluemix web interface doesn't appear even after a day...].

May I know what is the possible cause in this case?

Thanks in advance for any advise.

BRs,
KH

Comment: Could you please specify in which region are the spaces created and in which region you are creating your iot application?

Comment: I have been having this same problem since Friday.  I will report it to the Bluemix support team.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, to fix this kind of issue follow these steps:

1. logout
2. close browser
3. clean the cache and login in Bluemix console

If the issue is still there open a support request directly from your Bluemix console or you can open a new ticket here: https://support.ng.bluemix.net/gethelp/ .

Comment: This issue has been determined to be a defect and is being addressed.